# Can't find the roots for this function even though there is a global/local maximum, why?

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to find the roots for this function:

$$
f'(x) = \dfrac{w_0w_1y_0y_1\left(\frac{x_0}{x+x_0}\right)^\frac{w_0}{v_0}\left(\frac{x_1}{y_0\left(1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x+x_0}\right)^\frac{w_0}{v_0}\right)+x_1}\right)^\frac{w_1}{v_1}}{v_0v_1\left(x+x_0\right)\left(y_0\left(1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x+x_0}\right)^\frac{w_0}{v_0}\right)+x_1\right)}-1
$$

Which is the first derivative of this function of which I'm trying to find the maximum:

$$
f(x) = y_1\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x_1}{y_0\left(1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x+x_0}\right)^\frac{w_0}{v_0}\right)+x_1}\right)^\frac{w_1}{v_1}\right)-x
$$

I'm simply trying to use an online derivative calculator (https://www.derivative-calculator.net/) but it says no roots can be found for the derivative, which is strange since there is clearly a local/global maximum when plotted.

To see the plot in the website I've linked follow this steps:

1. Copy-paste this formula on the box

> y1*(1-(x1/(x1+(y0*(1-(x0/(x0+x))^(w0/v0)))))^(w1/v1))-x

2. Click on Go!
3. At the bottom on the page you can see the graph, you can use this example parameters:

x0 = 800

y0 = 500,000

x1 = 600,000

y1 = 1417

w0 = 0.8

v0 = 0.2

w1 = 0.15

v1 = 0.85

4. Now you can see that there is a global maximum on $ f(3.717) = 0.0772$

Does this function really have no roots?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really have time at all to look into this in any detail, but I will say that it's possible to have a global maximum but no zero. Consider $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + 1, f(0) = 2$ (with the extra condition to make it continuous.)  Or $e^{-x^2}$. Existence of a global maximum $\nRightarrow$ existence of a root.

Comment: maximums occur at critical points, as above,  so anywhere you have the derivative 0 or undefined.  Thus you have an automatic critical point at $-x_0$ and maybe some more, too tired to look further

Comment: I really appreciate both your inputs. In this case $x > 0$ always, so function is defined and is continuous for all the acceptable values of $x$. Also $w0,v0,w1,v1$ are always positive (non-zero).

Comment: By the way, is not possible at all then to calculate some sort of roots for this function, or something similar?